# Type error with numeric type classes

Tags: haskell

```
data V2 a = V2 a a deriving (Show, Eq)

instance Num a => Num (V2 a) where
    (-) (V2 x0 y0) (V2 x1 y1) = V2 (x0 - x1) (y0 - y1)
    (+) (V2 x0 y0) (V2 x1 y1) = V2 (x0 + x1) (y0 + y1)
    (*) (V2 x0 y0) (V2 x1 y1) = V2 (x0 * x1) (y0 * y1)
    abs = undefined
    signum = undefined
    fromInteger = undefined

instance Fractional a => Fractional (V2 a) where
    (/) (V2 x0 y0) (V2 x1 y1) = V2 (x0 / x1) (y0 / y1)
    recip = undefined
    fromRational = undefined

-- Multiply by scalar
(*$) :: Num a => V2 a -> a -> V2 a
(*$) (V2 x y) s = V2 (x * s) (y * s)

-- Length of the vector
len :: (Num a, Integral a, Floating b) => V2 a -> b
len (V2 x y) = sqrt $ fromIntegral $ x * x + y * y

normal :: (Num a, Integral a) => V2 a -> V2 a
normal v = v *$ (1 / len v)

{-

Math\V2.hs:31:20:
    Could not deduce (Fractional a) arising from a use of `/'
    from the context (Num a, Integral a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 normal :: (Num a, Integral a) => V2 a -> V2 a
      at Math\V2.hs:31:1-27
    Possible fix:
      add (Fractional a) to the context of
        the type signature for
          normal :: (Num a, Integral a) => V2 a -> V2 a
    In the second argument of `(*$)', namely `(1 / len v)'
    In the expression: v *$ (1 / len v)
    In an equation for `normal': normal v = v *$ (1 / len v)

Math\V2.hs:31:22:
    Could not deduce (Floating a) arising from a use of `len'
    from the context (Num a, Integral a)
      bound by the type signature for
                 normal :: (Num a, Integral a) => V2 a -> V2 a
      at Math\V2.hs:31:1-27
    Possible fix:
      add (Floating a) to the context of
        the type signature for
          normal :: (Num a, Integral a) => V2 a -> V2 a
    In the second argument of `(/)', namely `len v'
    In the second argument of `(*$)', namely `(1 / len v)'
    In the expression: v *$ (1 / len v)

-}
```

I am having trouble implementing the normal function above. How can get it to pass the type check?

Comment: You should remove `recip = undefined` since it has a reasonable default method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Three options:

- Change your type signature:

  ```
  normal :: (Integral a, Floating b) => V2 a -> V2 b
  ```

  And then specify a function to convert a `(Integral a) => V2 a` into a `(Floating b) => V2 b` and apply that to the `v` before the `*$`.
- Convert the `Floating` result from the `1 / len v` into an `Integral` value (`round`, etc.).
- Do as Landei suggests and force usage of `Floating` everywhere.

`len` takes in a `(Integral a) => V2 a` and returns a `(Floating b) => b`.  You then do `1 /` on the result, which still has type `(Floating b) => b`.  From your type of `*$`, it takes a `V2 a` and an `a`, but in this case you have `v :: (Integral a) => V2 a` and `(1 / len v) :: (Floating b) => b` which aren't equivalent types.

So you have to do some form of coercion *somewhere*.

Answer (score 1):

The minimal fix is just to change type signature for normal:

```
normal :: Floating a => V2 a -> V2 a
```

Here are the types:

```
sqrt :: Floating a => a -> a
```

So there's no reason for len to accept something other than `Floating`.

Answer (score 0):

How about...

```
len :: (Floating a) => V2 a -> a
len (V2 x y) = sqrt $ x * x + y * y

normal :: (Floating a) => V2 a -> V2 a
normal v = v *$ (1.0 / len v)
```

Of course that means that you need to convert a `V2 Int` before you can calculate the normal, but this is like you have to convert an Int before doing division.

Comment: But this is the usual behavior, it's the same as being not able to write `sqrt 4`.

Comment: @Landei: sure you can, that's the point of `fromInteger` in the `Num` class: integral literals are able to be transformed into any numeric type!

Answer (score -1):

Found it. As `len` is returning a floating, a needs to be floating in `normal`. Otherwise 
you can try to define

```
($*) :: Num a, ?b => V2 a -> b -> V2 a
```

Anyay

```
 normal :: (Num a, Integral a, Floating a) => V2 a -> V2 a
```

works

You can alternatively change you len definition to be

len :: (Num a ) => V2 a -> a

Comment: No it isn't, 1 :: (Num a) => a.

Comment: I realized, that's the len the problem